# Values don't get inserted into the DB, even tho I don't get any errors

Tags: java, postgresql

It connects to the server, the values are correct, as far as I can see, and I have idea why this doesn't work.

I have other projects doing the same thing and connecting to the same DB and still works.

```
public static void insertTicket(String fullname, String phone, long n01, long n02, long n03, long n04, long n05, long n06){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        final String URL = "myurl";
        final String USERNAME = "username";
        final String PASSWORD = "password";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        PreparedStatement pSt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tickets(fullname, n01, n02, n03, n04, n05, n06, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pSt.setString(1, fullname);
        pSt.setLong(2, n01);
        pSt.setLong(3, n02);
        pSt.setLong(4, n03);
        pSt.setLong(5, n04);
        pSt.setLong(6, n05);
        pSt.setLong(7, n06);
        pSt.setString(8, phone);

        pSt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I obviously changed the url, password and username.
Thanks for you time.

Comment: You just set the parameters, but you forgot to execute the statement.

Comment: Could be wrong but shouldn’t there be some sort of execute statement?

Comment: OMFG i'm such a dumbass. Thank you guys, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you *executing* that prepared statement. You've built the statement and populated it, but you're closing it without actually using it. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) for more info.